# Stress-ng: Writing an application program using execv to invoke stress-ng commands and return if it is success or failure

Tags: c++, c, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, stress-testing

Stress-ng: How to write an application program in C or Cpp using execv to invoke stress-ng commands for CPU and memory testing in MIPS and return its status if it is success or failure?
Given an executable stress-ng file that has been cross-compiled to MIPS32 version using its toolchain.

Sample stress-ng commands:

```
stress-ng --vm 8 --vm-bytes 80% -t 1h
stress-ng --cpu 8 --cpu-ops 800000
```

Comment: What did you try so far? What doesn't work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  You need to show what you've tried (an MCVE —[MCVE]) and what is causing trouble. Where are the commands coming from?  Why not use `system()`? Why `execv()` instead of `execvp()`? What output do you require?  Timing?  Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will suffice:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
        pid_t pid;
        int ret;

        char *stress_ng = "/usr/bin/stress-ng";

        char *argv_new[] = { stress_ng,
                "--vm",  "8", "--vm-bytes",  "80%",
                "-t", "2s", "-v", NULL  };
        char *env_new[] = { NULL };

        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "fork failed: %d (%s)\n",
                        errno, strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else if (pid == 0) {
                ret = execve(stress_ng, argv_new, env_new);
                if (ret < 0) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "execve failed: %d (%s)\n",
                                errno, strerror(errno));
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                _exit(ret);
        } else {
                /* Parent */
                int status;

                ret = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
                if (ret < 0) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "waitpid failed: %d (%s)\n",
                                errno, strerror(errno));
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                ret = WEXITSTATUS(status);
                printf("stress-ng returned: %d\n", ret);
        }
        exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Hi Colin, How can I parse the output of execve and return the statement "Successfully completed in 2.06s"?

Comment: Stress-ng returns 0 when it is successful, so you can just check for that with the WEXITSTATUS(status) return.

Comment: Yes that is true, but execv on execution will show logs , how can I hide them and just parse "Successfully completed in 30s" ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse the output from stress-ng, you need to create a pipe between the parent and child and the parent needs to read and parse the output over the pipe, something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int ret;
    int fds[2];

    char *stress_ng = "/usr/bin/stress-ng";

    char *argv_new[] = { stress_ng,
        "--vm",  "8", "--vm-bytes",  "80%",
        "-t", "2s", "-v", NULL  };
    char *env_new[] = { NULL };

    if (pipe(fds) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pipe failed: %d (%s)\n",
            errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed: %d (%s)\n",
            errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        //close(STDERR_FILENO);
        close(STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fds[0]);
        dup2(fds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(fds[1], STDERR_FILENO);
        ret = execve(stress_ng, argv_new, env_new);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "execve failed: %d (%s)\n",
                errno, strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        close(fds[1]);
        _exit(ret);
    } else {
        /* Parent */
        int status;
        FILE *fp;
        char buffer[1024];

        close(fds[1]);
        fp = fdopen(fds[0], "r");
        if (!fp) {
            fprintf(stderr, "fdopen failed: %d (%s)\n",
                errno, strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) {
            size_t len = strlen(buffer);
            if (len > 0)
                buffer[len - 1] = '\0';

            if (strstr(buffer, "completed"))
                printf("GOT: <%s>\n", buffer);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        close(fds[0]);

        ret = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "waitpid failed: %d (%s)\n",
                errno, strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        ret = WEXITSTATUS(status);
        printf("stress-ng returned: %d\n", ret);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Hi Colin, how can I execute multiple commands by initializing char *argv_new[ ] using the above code which is only for a single command?Could you please post the code for that? Let the 2 commands be stress-ng --vm 8 --vm-bytes 80% -t 1h, 
stress-ng --cpu 8 --cpu-ops 800000